"Um der Gottes willen!": Warum "der"?
Aus meiner Kindheit im oberdeutschen Sprachraum habe ich im Ohr:

um der Gott(e)s Wille(n)

Wofür man auch literarische Belege findet.

er bittelte und bettelte so um der Gotts Willen und fiel ins Knie (Widmann, Die katholische Mühle; link)
sag mir, was dich so schwermütig macht, um der Gottswillen (Buol, Früchte der Heimat; link)

Ebenso in einem Volkslied (zitiert in Der Übersetzer vom Mai 1980, link).

Und willst di denn nimme
Erbareme mei,
Wie kannst, um der Gotts wille,
Denn gar au so sei!

Sowie im Schweizerischen Idiotikon.

Um der Gotts Willeⁿ, Grōßvatter, hȫr ūf! (link)

Es stellt sich die Frage: Wie erklärt man der?

Kurze Antwort
In den Beispielen gehört der Artikel der nicht zum Genitiv Singular Gotts, sondern zum Genitiv Plural Willen.
Längere Antwort
Heutzutage wird üblicherweise die Doppelpräposition um … willen mit Genitiv verwendet, also zum Beispiel

um Gotts willen

Diese Doppelpräposition ist aus um der Willen enstaden, wobei der Willen der Genitiv Plural von Wille ist. Mit einem Genitivattribut sieht das so aus:

um der Willen Gotts

Man kann das aber auch mit vorangestelltem Genitiv schreiben. Dann würde heutzutage das ursprüngliche Genitivattribut den Artikel der ersetzen:

um der Gotts Willen

In den zitierten Beispielen, die alle schon etwas älter sind, wurde der Artikel der jedoch beibehalten:

um der Gotts Willen

In dem Zitat von Buol ist Gotts Willen offenbar sogar zu einem Substantiv, das dann als Ganzes im Genitiv Plural steht, verschmolzen:

um der Gottswillen


Aber um regiert normalerweise nicht den Genitiv; warum also um der Willen?

Ist das eine Hypothese? Hast du Belege?

Darauf, dass "Willen" hier Plural ist, wäre ich meiner Lebtag nicht gekommen
